# How to enable Mongo indexes in Rails test environment with Mongoid driver?

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid5

I have a MongoId model like this:

```
module Acme
  class Account
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :username

    index({'username': 1}, {unique: true})
  end
end
```

I want to write some unit tests but I want this index to be enabled while creating such models in my test suite.

It seems that index is not enabled by default.

Any clue?

P.S. I am working on Rails 4, with mongoid gem: `5.1.3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Acme::Account.create_indexes
```

will create the indexes. So you can call that in your test. For example in a `before :each` or `before :suite` block.

Comment: Although I do not understand why you have such a complex code in your `before :suite` block, I find your answer helpful to solve my problem. I will recommend an edit.